# Array element is modified

Tags: ruby

Here is my challenge.

```
a = ["1", "2"]
b = ["3", "4"]
a << b
a # => ["1","2",["3","4"]]
```

If I modify the value of `b[0]`, `a` also is changed.

```
b[0] = "5"
a # => ["1","2",["5","4"]]
```

After pushing `b` into `a`, `b` was modified. Why is `a` changed, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your second question is not clear. What do you mean by fixing it?

Comment: I assume you want `%w(1 2 3 4)` as the result. If I'm right, you can use `a.push(*b)`, and in this way, `a` will not change with `b`.

Comment: Say you enter a house in a blue T-shirt, then change into a red T-shirt. If anyone takes a photo of the house, would you expect a house with someone in a blue T-shirt, or a house with someone in a red T-shirt? "But it was me that changed clothes, why did the house change?" The house didn't, but its contents did.

Comment: [This visualisation](http://goo.gl/4YNv0Y) is instructive (Python instead of Ruby, but otherwise exactly the same).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array instance that is referenced by `b` and the one that is pushed into `a`, both are same instance - hence, modifying one will result in changes seen in other as well.

You can try:

```
a << b.dup
```

so that a copy of `b` is pushed into `a`.